# The whole website is out of whack after deleting Cache from within the Magento Admin Panel

Tags: cache, pagespeed, styles

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Porto theme
```

We have:

- Installed fresh Magento 2.4.2-p1
- used the Magento Migration Tool to migrate from Magento 1.9.4
- installed the Magento Porto theme
- Amasty installed a bunch of their extensions which broke the site; they then asked us to request that our hosting company disables the Pagespeed module which they have done but it broke things even more so they asked that the hosting company turns the Pagespeed module back on but it was not good so they advised to keep it off for that account in our VPS.

This was then working fine (as Amasty fixed their end and hosting disabled Pagespeed for that account) even yesterday and this morning but then I decided to delete all the different Caches by going to the Admin Panel and clicking the different buttons to delete Cache. Afterward, the website broke completely where it still has the colors, etc. but displays everything kind of in 1 column in the body of the front end and everything on the back end is text-based only. I've gone back to hosting asking them to make sure the Pagespeed module is turned off for that account. They have done that but it did not fix the problem. *The hosting company is suggesting we turn the Pagespeed module off for our entire hosting account but I'm afraid that will break the Magento 1.9.4 websites?*

**Any idea of what might be going on or how I can find out what is going on and how to fix this?**

I have done the following via SSH but it did not help:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

UPDATED:

I just found this article and asked our hosting company to delete Redis Cache as it has previously resolved the same issue:

[Magento site is frequently getting CACHE issue and failing to serve CSS, site is getting broken page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95306/magento-site-is-frequently-getting-cache-issue-and-failing-to-serve-css-site-is)

Answer (score 0):

Deploy content and check after that

php bin/magento s:s:d
This will generate all the static content which you might have flushed